# Need help with SimpleXML and retrieving HREF node value

Tags: php, xml, warnings, simplexml

I'm trying to retrieve the the HREF and echo it out using SimpleXML, but I keep getting the error message below.

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ...

```
<?php

$url = 'file.xml';

foreach(simplexml_load_file($url)->info->content->item as $it) {
    echo $it->site-page-href;
}

?> 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<info>
    <content>
        <item>
            <site>
                <page>
                    <href>http://domain.com</href>
                </page>
            </site>
        </item>
    </content>
<info>
```

Can anyone spot the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `echo $it->site-page-href;` 
   should be `echo
   $it->site->page->href;`
2. Your
   end tag should be `</info>`
3. You should not use `->info` as you
   are already at the root element.
   ie.
   `simplexml_load_file($url)->content->item`
   *not*
   `simplexml_load_file($url)->info->content->item`

Btw, finding all of the href nodes can be achieved more easily if you use [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php).

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
 $href = $xml->xpath(".//href");
 foreach($href as $h) {
    var_dump($h);
 }
```

Comment: I like your xpath example! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly use

```
echo $it->site->page->href;
```

instead

```
echo $it->site-page-href;
```

and end the `<info>` tag with `</info>` in your XML file.